# How to enable multithreading on this powershell script?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

Please help I am trying to pull registry information from remote machines (that are online) and store them in a log file. It is slow process across 3000 machines, and I was hoping someone can help me add multithreading to speed up the process

```
    $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
filter Check-Online {
    trap { continue }
    . {
      $timeout = 2000
      $obj = New-Object system.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
      $result = $obj.Send($_, $timeout)
      if ($result.status -eq 'Success') {1 }
    }
}
function Get-WebPage {
<#  
.SYNOPSIS  
   Downloads web page from site.
.DESCRIPTION
   Downloads web page from site and displays source code or displays total bytes of webpage downloaded
.PARAMETER Url
    URL of the website to test access to.
.PARAMETER UseDefaultCredentials
    Use the currently authenticated user's credentials  
.PARAMETER Proxy
    Used to connect via a proxy
.PARAMETER Credential
    Provide alternate credentials 
.PARAMETER ShowSize
    Displays the size of the downloaded page in bytes
.NOTES  
    Name: Get-WebPage
    Author: Boe Prox
    DateCreated: 08Feb2011        
.EXAMPLE  
    Get-WebPage -url "http://www.bing.com"

Description
------------
Returns the source code from bing.com -showsize
.EXAMPLE  
    Get-WebPage -url "http://www.bing.com" -ShowSize

Description
------------
Returns the size of the webpage bing.com in bytes.
#> 
[cmdletbinding(
    DefaultParameterSetName = 'url',
    ConfirmImpact = 'low'
)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $True,
            Position = 0,
            ParameterSetName = '',
            ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
            [string][ValidatePattern("^(http|https)\://*")]$Url,
        [Parameter(
            Position = 1,
            Mandatory = $False,
            ParameterSetName = 'defaultcred')]
            [switch]$UseDefaultCredentials,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $False,
            ParameterSetName = '')]
            [string]$Proxy,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $False,
            ParameterSetName = 'altcred')]
            [switch]$Credential,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $False,
            ParameterSetName = '')]
            [switch]$ShowSize                        

        )
Begin {     
    $psBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | % { 
        Write-Verbose "Parameter: $_" 
        }

    #Create the initial WebClient object
    Write-Verbose "Creating web client object"
    $wc = New-Object Net.WebClient 

    #Use Proxy address if specified
    If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Proxy')) {
        #Create Proxy Address for Web Request
        Write-Verbose "Creating proxy address and adding into Web Request"
        $wc.Proxy = New-Object -TypeName Net.WebProxy($proxy,$True)
        }       

    #Determine if using Default Credentials
    If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('UseDefaultCredentials')) {
        #Set to True, otherwise remains False
        Write-Verbose "Using Default Credentials"
        $wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $True
        }
    #Determine if using Alternate Credentials
    If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Credentials')) {
        #Prompt for alternate credentals
        Write-Verbose "Prompt for alternate credentials"
        $wc.Credential = (Get-Credential).GetNetworkCredential()
        }         

    }
Process {    
    Try {
        If ($ShowSize) {
            #Get the size of the webpage
            Write-Verbose "Downloading web page and determining size"
            "{0:N0}" -f ($wr.DownloadString($url) | Out-String).length -as [INT]
            }
        Else {
            #Get the contents of the webpage
            Write-Verbose "Downloading web page and displaying source code" 
            $wc.DownloadString($url)       
            }

        }
    Catch {
        Write-Warning "$($Error[0])"
        }
    }   
}  

Function Get-RemoteRegistry {
    #This Function is read remote registry
    param(
        [string]$computer = $(Read-Host "Remote Computer Name")
       ,[string]$Path     = $(Read-Host "Remote Registry Path (must start with HKLM,HKCU,etc)")
       ,[string[]]$Properties
       ,[switch]$Verbose
    )
    if ($Verbose) { $VerbosePreference = 2 } # Only affects this script.

       $root, $last = $Path.Split("\")
       $last = $last[-1]
       $Path = $Path.Substring($root.Length + 1,$Path.Length - ( $last.Length + $root.Length + 2))
       $root = $root.TrimEnd(":")

       #split the path to get a list of subkeys that we will need to access
       # ClassesRoot, CurrentUser, LocalMachine, Users, PerformanceData, CurrentConfig, DynData
       switch($root) {
          "HKLM"  { $root = "LocalMachine" }
          default { return "Path argument is not valid" }
       }


       #Access Remote Registry Key using the static OpenRemoteBaseKey method.
       Write-Verbose "Accessing $root from $computer"
       #Add-Content $loglocation "Accessing $root from $computer"
       $rootkey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($root,$computer)
       if(-not $rootkey) { Write-Error "Can't open the remote $root registry hive" }

       Write-Verbose "Opening $Path"
       #Add-Content $loglocation "Opening $Path"
       $key = $rootkey.OpenSubKey( $Path )
       if(-not $key) { 
       Write-Error "Can't open $($root + '\' + $Path) on $computer"
       #Add-Content $loglocation "Can't open $($root + '\' + $Path) on $computer"
       }

       $subkey = $key.OpenSubKey( $last )

       $output = new-object object

       if($subkey -and $Properties -and $Properties.Count) {
          foreach($property in $Properties) {
             Add-Member -InputObject $output -Type NoteProperty -Name $property -Value $subkey.GetValue($property)
          }
          Write-Output $output
       } elseif($subkey) {
          Add-Member -InputObject $output -Type NoteProperty -Name "Subkeys" -Value @($subkey.GetSubKeyNames())
          foreach($property in $subkey.GetValueNames()) {
             Add-Member -InputObject $output -Type NoteProperty -Name $property -Value $subkey.GetValue($property)
          }
          Write-Output $output
       }
       else
       {
          $key.GetValue($last)
       }
}


$loglocation = Read-Host "Please input a local path to save the logs to. Ex: C:\mylog.txt"
$Computerlist = Read-Host "Please input the path to local file that contains the computer's names. Ex: C:\computernames.txt"

$webpage = Get-WebPage -url "ftp://ftp.mcafee.com/commonupdater/"
$val1 = $webpage.indexof("avvdat-") + 4
$val2 = $webpage.indexof(".zip")
$output = $webpage.substring($val1,$val2-$val1)
$output = $output.replace("at-", "")
write-host "The current DAT file version is: $output"
Add-Content $loglocation "The current DAT file version is: $output"

$servers = get-content $Computerlist #read the computers from the text file

foreach($s in $servers){ #This foreach loops through the text file of computers and performs the below actions on each computer.
    #Check if they are online
    if (($s | Check-Online) -eq 1) {     
        write-host "$s is online"
        $Regvalue = Get-RemoteRegistry $s "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\AVEngine\AVDatDate"     
        $Regvalue2 = Get-RemoteRegistry $s "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\AVEngine\AVDatVersion"     
        $Regvalue3 = Get-RemoteRegistry $s "HKLM\SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine\AVDatDate"        
        $Regvalue4 = Get-RemoteRegistry $s "HKLM\SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVEngine\AVDatVersion" 

        $aValue = $Regvalue
        $bValue = $Regvalue2
        if($Regvalue -eq $null){
            $aValue = $Regvalue3
        }

        if($Regvalue2 -eq $null){
            $bValue = $Regvalue4
        }
        write-host $Regvalue
        write-host $Regvalue2
        write-host $Regvalue3
        write-host $Regvalue4
        Add-Content $loglocation "$s,$aValue,$bValue"
    }else{
        Write-Error "$s is offline"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you be using EPO for this? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The admins that control ePO do not allow us to access it. They are at the enterprise and don't give us the right tools to do our job.

Comment: Then why don't you kick responsibility for this task back to the people who control it?

Comment: We have tried, but it is going now where. Hence why I need to come up with something myself.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has the concept of jobs which can be run asynchronously and managed / monitored accordingly.  Apart from the ePO comment above, I'd recommend using the built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PSRemoting on all of those systems, you can use the Fan-Out approach and query all of the servers remotely using Invoke-Command.

```
$Servers = Get-Content Servers.txt
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {#Code to run} -Computername $Servers -AsJob -Throttle 20
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```